# Why does my while loop keep executing even when the value is true?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scope, cs50

I tried using the Do While loop originally but was having the same results as the while loop. The user must enter a number 28 - 31. Upon the first try if the user would enter the value correctly it would move on to the next part of the code. However, if the user enters an incorrect value it will ask for a number again but, no matter what they enter it keeps repeating.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {

     printf("Days in month: ");
     int daysInMonth = GetInt();    

     while (daysInMonth < 28 || daysInMonth > 31)
     {

         printf("Days in month: ");
         int daysInMonth = GetInt(); 

         printf("%i\n", daysInMonth);

     }

     printf("Pennies on the first day: ");
     int pennies = GetInt();

     while (pennies < 1)
     {

        printf("Pennies on the first day: ");
        int pennies = GetInt();

     }

}
```

The printf statement was for debugging purposes to test if `daysInMonth` is reassigning the value.

Comment: why are re-declaring `daysInMonth` and `pennies` ?

Comment: The declaration of the automatic object `daysInMonth` inside the `while()`-loop shadows the declaration of the automatic object of the same name outside of the loop.

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time, I'm just trying to lear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first `while`, you have:

```
 int daysInMonth = GetInt();
```

This defines a *new* variable `daysInMonth`, local for the `while`'s **body**, which hides the outer variable with the same name. So, in the **condition** of the `while` loop, you use the outer `daysInMonth`, in the body, you use the inner `daysInMonth`.

I guess you want to remove the `int` part from this row and just modify the outer `daysInMonth`.

Actually, you have the same situation in the second `while` loop.

Comment: I fixed both of them, thank you very much! I have definitely learned from this, and I'm sorry for wasting your time. I will mark the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: @TooDumbForThis - you're welcome, we're all here to help :) I'm glad, that I helped you to understand the issue, that's how we all learn new things. Good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

**TL:DR** you have **two** different variables named `daysInMonth` in your code, with overlapping *scope*, which creates the problem.

You have the same problem with `pennies` variable, too.

---

To elaborate,

```
int daysInMonth = GetInt();
```

creates a (*another*) variable which is local to the `while` loop body. It shadows the outer `daysInMonth` variable, so in the conditional check, the value never changes. Change to

```
  daysInMonth = GetInt();
```

*inside* the `while` loop body.

Quoting `c11`, chapter §6.2.1, *Scopes of identifiers*

> [...] If the declarator or type specifier that
>   declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in
>   a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block. [...]

and

> [...] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end
>   strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
>   scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**